# How many are there in "The 200"?

Tags: american-dad

In the episode of *American Dad* "The 200", towards the end of the episode it is revealed that the 200 are actually different incarnations of Roger.

I've never counted: how many Rogers are there, and does it account for all of his personas up until that point?

Comment: Every time i see this episode i make a new mental note to rewatch and count...i just always forgot, good question!

Answer (score 1):

This is the 200th episode of American Dad, which is also why its called the 200. Roger on average is at least in one costume an episode.. give or take episodes where he wears multiple outfits or wears previous outfits. Given this, its safe to assume that roger has had at least 200 personas since its the 200th episode. We the audience are suppose to assume that there are 200 but the animation team unlikely researched and drew every single costume. they just show about 50 naming themselves then show them fighting.

There have been reports that there are quite a few personas missing. For instance, Laura vanderboobin, the persona that got sexually harassed for money does not make an appearance. So we can assume its offscreen, but the episode does not at least draw or animate all 200 in the scene.

Comment: Do you have a source for this info? It’d be a +1 from me if so

Comment: Most of my answer was speculation other than the missing American Dad characters, which is just a matter of freeze framing the scenes and observing myself, and other people doing the same via a quick Google search. The 200 Rogers can be verified by checking the episode number 200 . I'm sure there's DVD commentary about it too.